# Django Model last Updated not updating correctly.

Tags: django-models

I'm using the below function to update models when there is a difference.
However even when there is an update to an instance of the model which I can see in the django shell or admin. The last updated field doesn't update and seems to be stuck when it was created even though it's using `auto_now=True`

```
def create_or_update_if_diff(self, model, defaults=None, **lookup):
    defaults = defaults or {}
    instance, created = model.objects.get_or_create(**lookup, defaults=defaults)
    if created:
        self.log_database_create(instance)
        return instance
    else:
        for key, value in defaults.items():
            attr = getattr(instance, key)
            if key == 'end_date_fixed' and value:  # Quick fix for Tariff type dif
                value = parse_date(value)  # Ideally should compare serialised vs serialised
            if attr != value:
                # If any change detected update all for efficiency
                model.objects.filter(**lookup).update(**defaults)
                self.log_database_update(instance)
                instance.refresh_from_db()
                return instance
        return instance
```

Model:

```
class ProductPrices(models.Model):
unique_id = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
name = models.ForeignKey(Product)
payment_method = models.ForeignKey(PaymentMethod)

# prices exclude VAT
unit_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=4, null=True)

saving = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
saving_percentage = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=2)

units = models.IntegerField()

last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is use of .update doesn't update fields with auto_now=True.

https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/22981